# search for string in file in ASSEMBLY

Tags: string, file, assembly

I need to write a program in ASSEMBLY to search for a string (input for keyboard) in all file of current folder.
What's interrupt can I use and what's algorithm of this program?

Comment: I suspect this will be fruitless, but what platform are you targeting?

Comment: The language doesn't really affect the algorithm(s) you'd want to use.

Comment: @Jerry: No, but he's asking for interrupts, which implies that he wants more than a general string-search algorithm.

Comment: @Mike: yes, I'd guess he's assuming those will be needed for things like enumerating the files in the directory. Under MS-DOS that would be true; otherwise it's much less so...

Comment: @Mike and Jerry: Thank all of you. The platorm is MS DOS 16 bits and this program's written by 8086 assembly languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm...here's some code I wrote (at least I *think* I wrote it -- it looks like code I'd have written, though it doesn't have any comments to confirm it) to list the files in a directory:

```
.model small, c

.stack

.data
    file_spec db "*.*", 0
    DTA db 128h dup(0)
    buffer db 30 dup(0)

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @Data
    mov ds, ax
    mov dx,offset DTA
    mov ah,1Ah
    int 21h ; set DTA location

    mov dx,offset file_spec
    xor cx, cx
    mov ah,4Eh
    int 21h
    jc  quit

print_name:
    lea si, DTA + 30
next_char:
    lodsb
    int 29h
    test al, al
    jnz next_char

    mov al, 13
    int 29h
    mov al, 10
    int 29h

    mov dx, offset file_spec
    xor cx, cx
    mov ah, 4fh
    int 21h
    jnc print_name
quit:   
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
main endp
    end main
```

Here's another that opens and displays a file:

```
data segment para public 'DATA'
line    db 80 dup(?)
file    db "test.txt"
handle  dw ?
data ends

code segment para public 'CODE'
assume ds:data
assume cs:code
main proc
    mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax

    ; okay.  First, open the file
    mov dx,offset file
    mov ax,3d00h
    int 21h

    mov handle,ax

read_loop:

    mov dx,offset line
    mov bx,handle
    mov cx, 80  ; the size of our buffer.
    mov ah,3fh

    int 21h

    jc  done

    test ax,ax
    jz  done

    mov bx,1
    mov cx,ax
    mov dx,offset line
    mov ah,40h
    int 21h
    jmp read_loop

done:

    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
main endp
code ends
        end main
```

Searching for the data in the file would be basically a matter of writing a `strstr` in assembly language. You'd probably want to start with a quick scan using `rep cmpsb` and then do a byte-by-byte comparison when you find a candidate match. If that fails, you increment the position and try again.